# Mac Pro (2013 - cylinder) Ubuntu 16.04.1 Live USB not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I have downloaded both Ubuntu and Xubuntu (for sanity check) and write the ISO to USB via Etcher on Mac and Rufus on Windows 7 (again to double check).

I have installed the latest reFInd and I have tried to boot the USB stick (the USB stick was used to boot other HP server etc.. so its not broken) in every combination I could think.

reFInd UFI boot, reFInd legacy boot, native OSX boot (via holding ALT key).

All of them hang here:

[image: boot screen]

OS X 10.11 ("El Capitan") System Integrity Protection (SIP) feature, aka "rootless" is disabled!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is with the GPU initialisation.

You can install the latest Ubuntu by using the Ubuntu Server 64bit ISO and build your GUI system on top of that.

'sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop' etc will do the trick.

This is not an easy install for the first time user!

EDIT: if you can afford it, go with Ubuntu 15.10 and not 16.04 as the ATI drivers are no longer supported.